# Catch InvMod error in NTL

Tags: c++, exception, ntl

I use archlinux, and I install ntl from pacman by default.

I have a problem with catching InvMod error in my code, maybe someone have the same problem, and now the solution for this:

```
try {
          Q = Q + p;
        } catch (...) {
          std::cout<<"error?";
          return;
        }
```

where in + operator I have inverse of modulo, because everything is inside the finite field.

I get this message:

```
InvMod: inverse undefined
fish: 'and ./crypto' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

I want to catch this error, because I need to know when I cannot inverse some point. Anyone know how to do this in ntl :)?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-changes.html), if you want it to throw an exception instead of just calling `abort()` - which it currently seems to be doing - you need to configure it with `NTL_EXCEPTIONS=on`.

Comment: Thanks, it's working, I compile the ntl localy, create FindNTL.cmake file, and is working at now thanks :)